# Flutter defining simple onTap don't trigger on nested class

Tags: flutter

In my application i have `SliverAppBar` class which i built it, in that i have `onTap` function which i want to pass click event from that to parent

```dart
class SliverAppBar extends StatelessWidget{
  final Function _onTap;

  const SliverAppBar({@required Function onTap}):_onTap=onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverPersistentHeader(
      pinned: false,
      floating: true,
      delegate: CustomAppBarDelegate(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                  size: 28.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('aaaaaaaaaaaa');

                  return _onTap;
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

when i click on `search` button i get this output in console:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaa
```

but i can't get this click event from outside as mean parent

```dart
SliverAppBar(onTap: () {
  print('clicked !!!');
}),
```

Comment: Have you tried like this `onPressed: _onTap,` ?

Comment: do as above comment says (preferred way), or `onPressed: () {
print('aaaaaaaaaaaa');
_onTap();
},`

Comment: @pskink thanks a lot dude, worked fine